# Does nudity invalidate marriage?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, sex

I searched the Internet, and found a fatwa from an Egyptian cleric about that, and I need to know if this is true?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that cleric married ?

Comment: Could you provide a source of that at least?

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong. Married couples can be nude with their partners, and those saying the opposite usually quote weak Hadiths. You can have more insight here. ([source](https://islamqa.info/en/45514))